# Install Gitlab on Mac OS 10.12 failed at 'Charlock_holmes (0.7.3)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, gitlab

I want to install Gitlab on Mac OS X. Therefore I followed

[Installation Guid for Gitlab on OS X](https://github.com/WebEntity/Installation-guide-for-GitLab-on-OS-X)

However, I get into trouble when I install ruby gems by bundle.

```
bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql aws kerberos
```

resulted in,

```
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/charlock_holmes-0.7.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing charlock_holmes (0.7.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.7.3'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  gitlab_git was resolved to 10.5.0, which depends on
    github-linguist was resolved to 4.7.6, which depends on
      charlock_holmes
```

I tried [Unable to install version 0.7.3 on Mac OS Sierra](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes/issues/117) in order to install **charlock_holmes**.

```
gem install charlock_holmes -v 0.7.3 -- --with-cxxflags=-std=c++11
```

it resulted in successfully installed.

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-cxxflags=-std=c++11'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed charlock_holmes-0.7.3
Parsing documentation for charlock_holmes-0.7.3
Done installing documentation for charlock_holmes after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

So I am confused why I can not keep install gems..

---

I install all gems by

> bundle install --no-deployment --without development test mysql aws kerberos

However, I got in other error...

> bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production

resulted in,

```
D, [2018-01-25T16:22:14.066436 #89351] DEBUG -- sentry: ** [Raven] compared with non class/module excluded from capture due to environment or should_capture callback
rake aborted!
TypeError: compared with non class/module
```

Comment: See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/blob/master/doc/howto/troubleshooting.md#charlock_holmes-07x-cannot-be-installed-on-macos-sierra for the first part, which looks like it succeeded.  The second part looks similar to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37361. Perhaps using the latest GitLab version or installing with https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem today. What fixed it for me was updating icu4c, then re-installing ruby which will compile with the updated version. I use `ruby-install` and `chruby` so it was basically like this:

`$ brew upgrade icu4c
$ chruby 2.3.4 # change to previous ruby (if necessary)
$ rm -rf .rubies/ruby-2.4.4 # drop ruby compiled with old version of icu4c
$ ruby-install ruby 2.4.4 # don't forget to restart your terminal after this completes
$ ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION'
2.4.4
$ bundle install # now it works!`